# Sitecore - What is the different between "is equal to", "is case-insensitively equal to" and "is not case-insensitively equal to"?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

In Sitecore, I am trying to create segmented list in the Line Manager. However, when I select the condition, I get so confuse with "is equal to", "is case-insensitively equal to" and "is not case-insensitively equal to"?

[image]

Can anyone explain the difference to me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below the code used by Sitecore for `Equals`, `CaseInsensitivelyEquals`, `NotEqual` and `NotCaseInsensitivelyEquals` operators:

```cs
case StringConditionOperator.Equals:
    return first == second;
case StringConditionOperator.CaseInsensitivelyEquals:
    return string.Compare(first, second, System.StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == 0;
case StringConditionOperator.NotEqual:
    return first != second;
case StringConditionOperator.NotCaseInsensitivelyEquals:
    return string.Compare(first, second, System.StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != 0;
```